# How to update app on google play

Tags: android, xamarin

im very new to the google play and mobile app world.

I would like to know the process of updating my app on the google play store as im not sure how. It is Android app.

I am using xamarin for the app. I have increased the version name to by .1 and if I do this, do I have to also increase the version number to 2 ? because it cannot take decimal points.

I have a simple understanding of It so im not sure if I have to create a new apk or update the existing one, and if so, how ?

and then on google play, do I just go and select the new apk, or updated apk ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number (or version code) it's an integer value used to determine whether one version is more recent than another. This is **not** shown to the end users. Every new version you make should have a higher number than the previous.  You can simply increase the number by one each time a new version is released.

The version name is a string, and it's only meant to be shown to users. It can be whatever you want, like "1.0" or "Beta 1.2.3".

To update an app you just upload a new apk to Google Play, and the system uses its version number to find out what's the newest apk ank make it visible by default.

Comment: O do I have to now vreate a new apk by going to project --> publish Android application... --> Then when it askes for use existing or create new keystore, I must create a new one ? or use the existing one ? Im using xamarin

Comment: I don't use xamarin, but yes, you should create a new apk (with a higher version code) with the same keystore. If you use another keystore, it won't have the correct signature and Google Play won't accept it. That's a security measure, that's why you should keep your keystore (and password) somewhere safe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good, detailed, step-by-step process at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/ (which also explains the difference between version # and version name, among other things). Definitely worth a read!

Comment: Hi man, iv go through that, but didn't mention the updating apk section, I understand the difference now between the 2 verion code and name, but updating the apk, not to sure if I have to create new keystore or use existing when publishing android app in xamarin.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you must use __exactly__ the same keystore you were using for the first version of the application you put up there. Basically all you need to do is rebuild (and re-sign) your application source code (with fixes, updates, etc.) to make your new APK and upload it as an update. As @MadEqua said, if the keystore is different, the Play store won't accept it as an update (this prevents people taking your app, hacking it to put in something nasty, re-signing it with their own keystore, and then uploading it as an update from you). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's and the help